# Return Name of first record df.iloc[0] using Python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I am new to Python and am trying to create a function that returns the Name of a record in a dataset using numpy.  I have sorted the data in descending order based on the column 'silver medals'to retrieve the record that I would like to return.  I'm sure there is an easier way to get the top value but I'm new to this and am trying to learn one step at a time....

```
df.sort_values(by=['silver medals'], inplace =True, ascending=False)
```

when I use

```
df.iloc[0]
```

to return the record details i can see at the bottom of the information it says:

Detail.....

Name: Country Name, dtype: object

I can use the below to return the abbreviated country name

```
df['ID'].iloc[0]
```

however I am trying to return the full name....  I believe the column that has the full name in it is index 0 and does not have any header data... so I'm not sure how to reference the column

I have tried the following but none of them seems to work.... what am i doing incorrectly?  Any help would be appreciated

```
   df[0].iloc[0]
   df[''].iloc[0]
   df[' '].iloc[0]
```

Comment: What is the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: The output is as follows (see below).... however in the column before '#Summer' there is data containing country names without a header.....

There was code before this that seems to have modified the index somehow:

[code]df.index = names_ids.str[0] # the [0] element is the country name[/code]

Columns:
[code]Index(['# Summer', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze', 'Total', '# Winter', 'Gold.1',
       'Silver.1', 'Bronze.1', 'Total.1', '# Games', 'Gold.2', 'Silver.2',
       'Bronze.2', 'Combined total', 'ID'],
      dtype='object')[/code]

Comment: Your index contains the country names. The index cannot be accessed like a column because it's not a column. You can put the index back into the columns by doing: `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: Happy to mark that as the answer.  Just let me know how I can do that...I don't see how I can mark your comment as the answer.

Comment: I moved the comment to an answer. Glad we could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your index contains the country names.
The index cannot be accessed like a column because it's not a column.
You can put the index back into the columns by doing: `df = df.reset_index()`